# Is this possible to add hook in an array?

Tags: wordpress, hook, advanced-custom-fields

For example I have following array with 2 options. I want to insert 3rd or more options from out side this array.

```
$options = array (
   'title' => 'some options',
   'fields' => array (
    array (
        //option1
    ),
    array (
        //option2
    ),
     //do_action('more_options'),
 );
```

I know do_action does not work here. But I need some alternative. Any idea or help would be great.

Comment: This is pretty broad...But you may be looking for [`apply_filters()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this an array of fields that you want to pass to ACF? If I'm correct, then the commenter above is correct that `apply_filters` is what you are looking for.

Your code would look like:

`$options = array(...);
register_field_group(apply_filters( 'my_custom_field_filter', $options ));`

You could then use that filter to append items to the array from anywhere else in your code, similar to an action hook.